# How can I make one part of my webpage move when I open the vertical menu

Tags: html, css

Good day,
I have a web page that displays several images, texts and also a vertical menu. When I click on the three horizontal bars, when the menu unfolds, I realise that it overlaps the rest of my page. I would like that my entire page shifts horizontaly accordingly.

How can I easily achieve that ? I hope that my explanations as well as the screenshots and the code below will help you to understand my issue. Thanks for your time and your help.

[image]
[image].

my html page :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">      
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Domoos mobile</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle_mobile.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/navimobile.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/navimobile.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
    <header class="banner" id="header" role="banner">
        <div id="domoos_logo"><img src="assets/icons/logo_Domoos_lab.png" alt="" style="width:75px;height:54px;"></div>
        <div id="tag_domoos_title">Domoos mobile</div>
        <div id="datetime">
            <script type="text/javascript">window.onload = getTimeDate('datetime');</script>
        </div>
        <div id="tag_sunrise_sunset"><p><img src="assets/icons/sun_icon.png" alt="" width="14" height="14">&#8593; 06:25 &#8595; 20:33</p></div>
    </header>
    <div id="current_weather_conditions_title">Conditions météo actuelles</div>
    <div id="tag_additional_weather_information">
        <Marquee Behavior="scroll" Scrolldelay="180">Vent 15 km/h SO &#0149; Humidit&#233; 79%  &#149; Pression 1011.4 hPa  &#149; Derni&#232;re mise &#224; jour: 18.08.2016 17:15
        </Marquee>
    </div>
    <div id="tag_weather_temperature">24&deg;C</div>
    <div id="tag_weather_condition">Pluie faible</div>
    <div id="meteo_icon"><img src="assets/meteo_icons/neige-forte-big.png" alt="" style="width:40px;height:40px;"></div>
    <div id="current_weather_forecast_title">Prévisions météorologiques</div>
    <div id="meteo_forecast_day1">
        <p>Samedi 20.08.2016</p>
    </div>
    <div id="meteo_forecast_temperature_day1">
        <p>12&deg;C | 20&deg;C</p>
    </div>
    <div id="meteo_forecast_condition_day1">
        <p><img src="assets/meteo_icons/pluie-moderee.png" alt="" width="18" height="18"> Pluie mod&#233r&#233e</p>
    </div>
    <div id="meteo_forecast_day2">
        <p>Dimanche 21.08.2016</p>
    </div>
    <div id="meteo_forecast_condition_day2">
        <p><img src="assets/meteo_icons/eclaircies.png" alt="" width="18" height="18"> Pluie mod&#233r&#233e</p>
    </div>
    <div id="meteo_forecast_temperature_day2">
        <p>-12&deg;C | -20&deg;C</p>
    </div>
    <div id="meteo_forecast_day3">
        <p>Lundi 22.08.2016</p>
    </div>
    <div id="meteo_forecast_temperature_day3">
        <p>12&deg;C | 20&deg;C</p>
    </div>
    <div id="meteo_forecast_condition_day3">
        <p><img src="assets/meteo_icons/ensoleille.png" alt="" width="18" height="18"> Faibles passages nuageux</p>
    </div>
    <div id="hyperlinks_mobile">
        <a href="home_mobile.html">Domoos home</a>
        &#0149;
        <a href="domotics1.html">Domotique</a>
        &#0149;
        <a href="domotics1.html">Chambres</a>
        &#0149;
        <a href="domotics1.html">SDB / WC</a>
        &#0149;   
        <a href="domotics1.html">WC Visiteurs</a>
        &#0149;
        <a href="domotics1.html">Entrée</a>
        &#0149;
        <a href="domotics1.html">Salon</a>
        &#0149;
        <a href="domotics1.html">Cuisine</a>
        &#0149;
        <a href="domotics1.html">Terrasse</a>
    </div>
        <span style="font-size:20px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
        <div class="footer" id="footer">Domoos web mobile version 0.0</div>
</body>
</html>
```

my mystyle_mobile css file :

```
#tag_domoos_title{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 150%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 130px;
    color:blue;
    z-index:10;
    font-weight: 900;
}

#tag_update{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 90px;
    color:blue;
}

#datetime{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 130px;
    color:blue;
}

#tag_sunrise_sunset{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    color:black;
}

#tag_weather_temperature{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 145px;
    right: 15px;
    color:black;
    font-weight: 900;
}

#current_weather_conditions_title{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 95%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110px;
    left: 10px;
    color:blue;
    font-weight: 900;
}

#current_weather_forecast_title{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 95%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 10px;
    color:blue;
    font-weight: 900;
}

#tag_weather_condition{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 130px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#tag_additional_weather_information{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 100px;
}

#meteo_forecast{
    font-family:Arial;  
    font-size: 100%;
    float:left;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    height:434px;
    width:870px;
    top:200px;
    position: relative;
}

#meteo_forecast_day1{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 215px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#meteo_forecast_day2{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 285px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#meteo_forecast_day3{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 355px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#meteo_forecast_temperature_day1{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 215px;
    right: 5px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_forecast_temperature_day2{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 285px;
    right: 5px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_forecast_temperature_day3{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 355px;
    right: 5px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_forecast_condition_day1{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 235px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_forecast_condition_day2{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 305px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_forecast_condition_day3{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 375px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
}

#domoos_logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 0px;
}

#lorem{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 10px;
    height: auto;
}

#footer
{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 40%;
    clear: both;
    border: 1px groove #aaaaaa;
    background: blue;
    color: White;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

#hyperlinks_mobile
{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
}

ul {
  background: #bbb;
}
li, [class*="grid"] > * {
  background: #ccc;
}
header, footer {
  background: #ddd;
}
body {
    background-color:#ddd;
}
```

my navimobile css file  :

```
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

my javascript :

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use relative positioning instead of absolute?

Comment: I might be totally wrong but thought that with the 'absolute', I would better be able to control the position of each and every element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code working fine here please check with the snippet

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
     padding: 30px;
    }
    .sidenav {
     height: 100%;
     width: 0;
     position: fixed;
     z-index: 1;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     background-color: #111;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     transition: 0.5s;
     padding-top: 60px;
     text-align: center;
    }
    .sidenav a {
     padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 25px;
     color: #818181;
     display: block;
     transition: 0.3s
    }
    .sidenav a:hover {
     color: #f1f1f1;
    }
.sidenav .closebtn {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 25px;
     font-size: 36px;
     margin-left: 50px;
    }
     @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {
     padding-top: 15px;
    }
    .sidenav a {
     font-size: 18px;
    }
    }
```

```html
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a> <a href="#">About</a> <a href="#">Services</a> <a href="#">Clients</a> <a href="#">Contact</a> </div>
    <header class="banner" id="header" role="banner">
          <div id="domoos_logo"><img src="assets/icons/logo_Domoos_lab.png" alt="" style="width:75px;height:54px;"></div>
          <div id="tag_domoos_title">Domoos mobile</div>
          <div id="datetime"> 
        <script type="text/javascript">window.onload = getTimeDate('datetime');</script> 
      </div>
          <div id="tag_sunrise_sunset">
        <p><img src="assets/icons/sun_icon.png" alt="" width="14" height="14">&#8593; 06:25 &#8595; 20:33</p>
      </div>
        </header>
    <div id="current_weather_conditions_title">Conditions météo actuelles</div>
    <div id="tag_additional_weather_information">
          <Marquee Behavior="scroll" Scrolldelay="180">
      Vent 15 km/h SO &#0149; Humidit&#233; 79%  &#149; Pression 1011.4 hPa  &#149; Derni&#232;re mise &#224; jour: 18.08.2016 17:15
      </Marquee>
        </div>
    <div id="tag_weather_temperature">24&deg;C</div>
    <div id="tag_weather_condition">Pluie faible</div>
    <div id="meteo_icon"><img src="assets/meteo_icons/neige-forte-big.png" alt="" style="width:40px;height:40px;"></div>
    <div id="current_weather_forecast_title">Prévisions météorologiques</div>
    <div id="meteo_forecast_day1">
          <p>Samedi 20.08.2016</p>
        </div>
    <div id="meteo_forecast_temperature_day1">
          <p>12&deg;C | 20&deg;C</p>
        </div>
    <div id="meteo_forecast_condition_day1">
          <p><img src="assets/meteo_icons/pluie-moderee.png" alt="" width="18" height="18"> Pluie mod&#233r&#233e</p>
        </div>
    <div id="meteo_forecast_day2">
          <p>Dimanche 21.08.2016</p>
        </div>
    <div id="meteo_forecast_condition_day2">
          <p><img src="assets/meteo_icons/eclaircies.png" alt="" width="18" height="18"> Pluie mod&#233r&#233e</p>
        </div>
    <div id="meteo_forecast_temperature_day2">
          <p>-12&deg;C | -20&deg;C</p>
        </div>
    <div id="meteo_forecast_day3">
          <p>Lundi 22.08.2016</p>
        </div>
    <div id="meteo_forecast_temperature_day3">
          <p>12&deg;C | 20&deg;C</p>
        </div>
    <div id="meteo_forecast_condition_day3">
          <p><img src="assets/meteo_icons/ensoleille.png" alt="" width="18" height="18"> Faibles passages nuageux</p>
        </div>
    <div id="hyperlinks_mobile"> <a href="home_mobile.html">Domoos home</a> &#0149; <a href="domotics1.html">Domotique</a> &#0149; <a href="domotics1.html">Chambres</a> &#0149; <a href="domotics1.html">SDB / WC</a> &#0149; <a href="domotics1.html">WC Visiteurs</a> &#0149; <a href="domotics1.html">Entrée</a> &#0149; <a href="domotics1.html">Salon</a> &#0149; <a href="domotics1.html">Cuisine</a> &#0149; <a href="domotics1.html">Terrasse</a> </div>
    <span style="font-size:20px;cursor:pointer; position:absolute; top:15px; left:15px;" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
<div class="footer" id="footer">Domoos web mobile version 0.0</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see code your html. I think you only fix css:

```
.sidenav {
height: 100%;
width: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: 20;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: #111;
overflow-x: hidden;
transition: 0.5s;
padding-top: 60px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can add margin left to your body

see this link

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly where I took my comment from.
What I put in my code was :
[...]
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
[...]
Did I miss something`?